# When I attempt to sort a column in a csv file that contains numerical data, is doesn't sort in the way I expect it to

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sorting

I am attempting to write a program that asks the user by which column in a csv file they wish to sort by, and generate a new csv file sorted by the requested column, with some columns containing strings and others containing integers and others floats.  When I attempt to sort by columns that contain integers or floats, it doesn't sort then in the way that I would like it to.  It's almost as if it's sorting the numbers 'alphabetically', if that makes sense.

In short, I am having problems attempting to sort numerical columns correctly.

I'm trying it only importing the csv module.

```
import csv


user_input = input("What would you like to sort by? (Country,Name, GDPPC, Literacy, InfantMortality, Agriculture, Population, NetMigration)")


with open('Countries.csv', 'r', newline='') as input_file:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    data = sorted(csv_input,reverse=True, key=lambda row: (row[user_input]))

with open('Countries_Sorted.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=csv_input.fieldnames)
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(data)


with open('Countries_Sorted.csv', 'r') as final_file:
    for line in final_file:
        print(line)
```

If I attempt to sort for example by Population, I get something like this...

```
Population
99390000
9845000
9799000
9651000
9513000
92900
91700000
9157000
91510000
892145
```

---

When it should generate something like this...

```
Population
1371000000
1311000000
321400000
257600000
207800000
188900000
182200000
161000000
144100000
127000000
```

Comment: Thats' because It _is_ sorting alphabetically, because the `csv` module returns the data a strings—so you'll need to manually convert it to the proper numeric type yourself.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html under csv.reader, when it parses your file I believe it returns string objects, so your numbers are actually represented as strings when you sort them. You will need to cast them to integers/floats first to sort them as numbers.